# iOS 7 CoreBluetooth retrievePeripheralsWithIdentifiers not Retrieving

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ipad, ios7, core-bluetooth

I am having an issue updating my CoreBluetooth code from iOS 6 to iOS 7. I can scan for Peripherals and make connections, however, I am not able to reconnect a Peripheral using the new CoreBluetooth methods offered within iOS 7. Here is a look at how I am trying to accomplish the reconnection:

```
- (void)retrievePeripheral:(NSString *)uuidString
{

NSUUID *nsUUID = [[NSUUID UUID] initWithUUIDString:uuidString];

if(nsUUID)
{        
    NSArray *peripheralArray = [centralManager retrievePeripheralsWithIdentifiers:@[nsUUID]];

    // Check for known Peripherals
    if([peripheralArray count] > 0)
    {
        for(CBPeripheral *peripheral in peripheralArray)
        {
            NSLog(@"Connecting to Peripheral - %@", peripheral);

            [self connectPeripheral:peripheral];
        }
    }
    // There are no known Peripherals so we check for connected Peripherals if any
    else
    {
        CBUUID *cbUUID = [CBUUID UUIDWithNSUUID:nsUUID];

        NSArray *connectedPeripheralArray = [centralManager retrieveConnectedPeripheralsWithServices:@[cbUUID]];

        // If there are connected Peripherals
        if([connectedPeripheralArray count] > 0)
        {
            for(CBPeripheral *peripheral in connectedPeripheralArray)
            {
                NSLog(@"Connecting to Peripheral - %@", peripheral);

                [self connectPeripheral:peripheral];
            }
        }
        // Else there are no available Peripherals
        else
        {
            // No Dice!
            NSLog(@"There are no available Peripherals");
        }
    }
}

}
```

Where uuidString is the saved Peripheral UUID.

I am always getting to the NSLog statement where there are no available Peripherals. I suppose I am missing something very obvious and someone can point me in the right direction.

In addition, I have read other posts about the iOS 7 update issues with CoreBluetooth and have tried reseting the BLE device and the iOS device but to no avail.

Thanks in Advance!
audible

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out that my mistake dealt with how I was converting the Peripheral's identifier into an `NSString` format before sending a message to my retrievePeripheral method.

This was the incorrect way:

```
NSString *uuidString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", CFUUIDCreateString(NULL, (__bridge CFUUIDRef)([peripheral identifier]))];
```

This was the correct way (that worked in my scenario):

```
NSString *uuidString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[peripheral identifier] UUIDString]];
```

According to the Apple Documentation the `NSUUID` Class is not toll-free bridged with CoreFoundation's `CFUUIDRef` as described below:

> Note: The `NSUUID` class is not toll-free bridged with CoreFoundation’s `CFUUIDRef`. Use UUID strings to convert between `CFUUID` and `NSUUID`, if needed. Two `NSUUID` objects are not guaranteed to be comparable by pointer value (as `CFUUIDRef` is); use `isEqual:` to compare two `NSUUID` instances.

For those of you who like a visual representation of what this means like I do here is an example:)

The Peripheral information printed within the Console:

```
<CBPeripheral: 0x14699430 identifier = DD2468AB-1865-B926-7FA4-AE3755D479D8, Name = "IDYNAMO EMV-A27F", state = disconnected>
```

The incorrect way of converting the Peripheral's identifier into an `NSString` yields:

```
1865B926-7FA4-AE37-55D4-79D800000000
```

The correct way of converting the Peripheral's identifier into an `NSString` yields:

```
DD2468AB-1865-B926-7FA4-AE3755D479D8
```

I hope this helps someone on their BLE journey and feel free to correct me if I am wrong in any way as I am still learning this stuff as well.

Thanks!

audible

Comment: I am wondering if you can help me with my code to convert to retrievePeripheralsWithIdentifiers

- (void) centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central
  didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)aPeripheral
      advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData
                   RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI
{
    
    NSMutableArray *peripherals = [self mutableArrayValueForKey:@"heartRateMonitors"];
    if(![self.heartRateMonitors containsObject:aPeripheral])
        [peripherals addObject:aPeripheral];
    
    [self.manager retrievePeripherals:[NSArray arrayWithObject:(id)aPeripheral.UUID]];
}

Answer (score 1):

This is an old post, but for others looking for answers.

The second/next call to retrieveConnectedPeripherals actually needs the Service UUID (CBUUID type), not the iOS first-time-connected-NSUUID. What is retrieved is a list och peripherals that has that service UUID implemented. For example if you have a number of activity armbands and all have your needed heartbeat service among other things, you will be retrieveing all 3 peripherals. Also in first call to KNOWN peripherals, you have to store the NSUUID between the app starts since that ID is created by iOS at first connect. Hope that helps