# which serviceUUIDs do I need to pass to retrieveConnectedPeripheralsWithServices to get any connected device in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, bluetooth

I'm trying to list the devices that are currently connected to my iPhone via Bluetooth using swift. I want any device (BLE, Classic Bluetooh...)

I'm using CoreBluetooth in Xcode 7.3 and swift 2.2

```
//CoreBluetooth methods
func centralManagerDidUpdateState(central: CBCentralManager)
{
    if (central.state == CBCentralManagerState.PoweredOn)
    {
        self.centralManager?.retrieveConnectedPeripheralsWithServices(**HERE**)
    }
    else
    {
        // do something like alert the user that ble is not on
    }
}

func centralManager(central: CBCentralManager, didDiscoverPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : AnyObject], RSSI: NSNumber)
{
    allPeripherals.append(peripheral)

}
```

I can not compile the project because I do not know what to pass as a parameter to the function **retrieveConnectedPeripheralsWithServices** to get all the connected devices.

Thanks for you help.

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25865937/how-to-detect-if-a-iphone-is-connected-to-any-bluetooth-device-or-not

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation you should enter an NSArray with CBUUID objects. These service UUID's has to be among the ones that have previously been discovered for that peripheral on this device. Typically you would type in the same uuid's that you use when you are scanning for the peripheral.

On Objective-C at least this is an example of what you could use:

```
@[[CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"]]
```

I obviously don't know which uuid you need.

Comment: do you know if I can get these UUID's some how from the system?

Answer (score 0):

After investigating, you can not find classic devices using CoreBluetooh, you need to use ExternalAccessory framework. Here a code that is working to get the currently "classic" devices connected:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,CLLocationManagerDelegate,CBCentralManagerDelegate, EAAccessoryDelegate{

var locationManager:CLLocationManager=CLLocationManager()
let accuracy=kCLLocationAccuracyBest


var centralManager: CBCentralManager?
var allPeripherals: Array<CBPeripheral> = Array<CBPeripheral>()
var connectedPheripherals: Array<CBPeripheral> = Array<CBPeripheral>()

var eaccessory:EAAccessoryManager?

@IBAction func putAction(sender: AnyObject) {
    //        GPS info
    let latitude=locationManager.location?.coordinate.latitude
    let longitude=locationManager.location?.coordinate.longitude
    let altitude=locationManager.location?.altitude
    let verticalAccuracy=locationManager.location?.verticalAccuracy
    let horizontalAccuracy=locationManager.location?.horizontalAccuracy
    let speed=locationManager.location?.speed

    //          Carrier info
    let networkInfo = CTTelephonyNetworkInfo()
    let carrier = networkInfo.subscriberCellularProvider
    let carrierName = carrier!.carrierName

    //          Phone's info
    let phone=UIDevice.currentDevice()
    let model=phone.model
    let os=phone.systemName

    //          Bluetooth's info
    for d in (eaccessory?.connectedAccessories)!
    {
        print("name: \(d.name)")
        print("modelNumber: \(d.modelNumber)")
        print("MAC: \(d.valueForKey("macAddress"))")
    }
}


func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateToLocation newLocation: CLLocation, fromLocation oldLocation: CLLocation) {

}

private func sendRequest(latitude:CLLocationDegrees, longitude:CLLocationDegrees, accuracy: CLLocationAccuracy)
{

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: dispatch_get_main_queue())

    locationManager.delegate=self

    eaccessory = EAAccessoryManager.sharedAccessoryManager()

    locationManager.desiredAccuracy=accuracy
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates=true
    locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically=false
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


//CoreBluetooth methods
func centralManagerDidUpdateState(central: CBCentralManager)
{
    if (central.state == CBCentralManagerState.PoweredOn)
    {
        //self.centralManager?.retrieveConnectedPeripheralsWithServices
    }
    else
    {
        // do something like alert the user that ble is not on
    }
}

func centralManager(central: CBCentralManager, didDiscoverPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : AnyObject], RSSI: NSNumber)
{
    allPeripherals.append(peripheral)


}
```

}

If you want to list the BLE devices, then you need to use the CoreBluetooth framework and the method `retrieveConnectedPeripheralsWithServices` who will receive an array of CBUUID. These array must be filled with the service UUID that you want to discover. Some of these are listed here: https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/services

Comment: Oh yep, sorry I missed the part about Bluetooth Classic in your original question. My answer is only for BTLE